# How to verify the Signature of a JWT generated by AWS Cognito in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-3.6, amazon-cognito

Here's my script

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time
from jose import jwk, jwt
from jose.utils import base64url_decode
import base64


region = '....'
userpool_id = '.....'
app_client_id = '...' 
keys_url = 'https://cognito-idp.{}.amazonaws.com/{}/.well-known/jwks.json'.format(region, userpool_id)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(keys_url)
keys = json.loads(response.read())['keys']
token = request.headers['Authorization']
print(token)
# get the kid from the headers prior to verification
headers = jwt.get_unverified_headers(request.headers['Authorization'])
kid = headers['kid']

print(kid)
# search for the kid in the downloaded public keys
key_index = -1
for i in range(len(keys)):
    if kid == keys[i]['kid']:
        key_index = i
        break
if key_index == -1:
    print('Public key not found in jwks.json')
    return False
# construct the public key
public_key = jwk.construct(keys[key_index])
# get the last two sections of the token,
# message and signature (encoded in base64)
message, encoded_signature = str(token).rsplit('.', 1)
# decode the 
print('>>encoded signature')
print(encoded_signature)
decoded_signature = base64.b64decode(encoded_signature)
if not public_key.verify(message, decoded_signature):
    print('Signature verification failed')
    return False
print('Signature successfully verified')
```

I am always ending up Signature verification failed even though  jwt token is generated by a valid legitimate cognito user pool. I've looked at the documentation and it does not really specify the whole verification process.

Comment: I'm running into this too. It fails every time, no idea why. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 12):

I see you're using jose, and I'm using pyjwt, but this solution might help you. Most of the bulk code from the bottom comes from the "api-gateway-authorizer-python" blueprint. Note that this is very frail code that will just break if anything is fails, I ended up not using lambda authentication but rather selecting AWS_IAM authentication for my API Gateway with Identity Pools so I never finished it.

This example requires that you install pyjwt and cryptography with pip on your work directory and upload everything as a .zip file.

I'd recommend that you watch this video if you want to consider the AWS_IAM authentication option: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZqG7HjT2AQ

They also have a solution with a more elaborate lambda authorizer implementation in github at: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-auth-reference-app (they show the link at the beggining of the video) but I don't know about their pip dependencies.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from jwt.algorithms import RSAAlgorithm

import re
import jwt
import json
import sys
import urllib

region = 'your-region'
userpoolId = 'your-user-pool-id'
appClientId = 'your-app-client-id' 
keysUrl = 'https://cognito-idp.{}.amazonaws.com/{}/.well-known/jwks.json'.format(region, userpoolId)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bearerToken = event['authorizationToken']
    methodArn = event['methodArn']
    print("Client token: " + bearerToken)
    print("Method ARN: " + methodArn)

    response = urllib.urlopen(keysUrl)
    keys = json.loads(response.read())['keys']

    jwtToken = bearerToken.split(' ')[-1]
    header = jwt.get_unverified_header(jwtToken)
    kid = header['kid']

    jwkValue = findJwkValue(keys, kid)
    publicKey = RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(jwkValue))

    decoded = decodeJwtToken(jwtToken, publicKey)
    print('Decoded token: ' + json.dumps(decoded))
    principalId = decoded['cognito:username']

    methodArn = event['methodArn'].split(':')
    apiGatewayArnTmp = methodArn[5].split('/')
    awsAccountId = methodArn[4]

    policy = AuthPolicy(principalId, awsAccountId)
    policy.restApiId = apiGatewayArnTmp[0]
    policy.region = methodArn[3]
    policy.stage = apiGatewayArnTmp[1]
    #policy.denyAllMethods()
    policy.allowAllMethods()

    # Finally, build the policy
    authResponse = policy.build()

    # new! -- add additional key-value pairs associated with the authenticated principal
    # these are made available by APIGW like so: $context.authorizer.<key>
    # additional context is cached
    context = {
        'key': 'value',  # $context.authorizer.key -> value
        'number': 1,
        'bool': True
    }
    # context['arr'] = ['foo'] <- this is invalid, APIGW will not accept it
    # context['obj'] = {'foo':'bar'} <- also invalid

    authResponse['context'] = context

    return authResponse

def findJwkValue(keys, kid):
    for key in keys:
        if key['kid'] == kid:
            return key

def decodeJwtToken(token, publicKey):
    try:
        decoded=jwt.decode(token, publicKey, algorithms=['RS256'], audience=appClientId)
        return decoded
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise

class HttpVerb:
    GET = 'GET'
    POST = 'POST'
    PUT = 'PUT'
    PATCH = 'PATCH'
    HEAD = 'HEAD'
    DELETE = 'DELETE'
    OPTIONS = 'OPTIONS'
    ALL = '*'


class AuthPolicy(object):
    # The AWS account id the policy will be generated for. This is used to create the method ARNs.
    awsAccountId = ''
    # The principal used for the policy, this should be a unique identifier for the end user.
    principalId = ''
    # The policy version used for the evaluation. This should always be '2012-10-17'
    version = '2012-10-17'
    # The regular expression used to validate resource paths for the policy
    pathRegex = '^[/.a-zA-Z0-9-\*]+$'

    '''Internal lists of allowed and denied methods.

    These are lists of objects and each object has 2 properties: A resource
    ARN and a nullable conditions statement. The build method processes these
    lists and generates the approriate statements for the final policy.
    '''
    allowMethods = []
    denyMethods = []

    # The API Gateway API id. By default this is set to '*'
    restApiId = '*'
    # The region where the API is deployed. By default this is set to '*'
    region = '*'
    # The name of the stage used in the policy. By default this is set to '*'
    stage = '*'

    def __init__(self, principal, awsAccountId):
        self.awsAccountId = awsAccountId
        self.principalId = principal
        self.allowMethods = []
        self.denyMethods = []

    def _addMethod(self, effect, verb, resource, conditions):
        '''Adds a method to the internal lists of allowed or denied methods. Each object in
        the internal list contains a resource ARN and a condition statement. The condition
        statement can be null.'''
        if verb != '*' and not hasattr(HttpVerb, verb):
            raise NameError('Invalid HTTP verb ' + verb + '. Allowed verbs in HttpVerb class')
        resourcePattern = re.compile(self.pathRegex)
        if not resourcePattern.match(resource):
            raise NameError('Invalid resource path: ' + resource + '. Path should match ' + self.pathRegex)

        if resource[:1] == '/':
            resource = resource[1:]

        resourceArn = 'arn:aws:execute-api:{}:{}:{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(self.region, self.awsAccountId, self.restApiId, self.stage, verb, resource)

        if effect.lower() == 'allow':
            self.allowMethods.append({
                'resourceArn': resourceArn,
                'conditions': conditions
            })
        elif effect.lower() == 'deny':
            self.denyMethods.append({
                'resourceArn': resourceArn,
                'conditions': conditions
            })

    def _getEmptyStatement(self, effect):
        '''Returns an empty statement object prepopulated with the correct action and the
        desired effect.'''
        statement = {
            'Action': 'execute-api:Invoke',
            'Effect': effect[:1].upper() + effect[1:].lower(),
            'Resource': []
        }

        return statement

    def _getStatementForEffect(self, effect, methods):
        '''This function loops over an array of objects containing a resourceArn and
        conditions statement and generates the array of statements for the policy.'''
        statements = []

        if len(methods) > 0:
            statement = self._getEmptyStatement(effect)

            for curMethod in methods:
                if curMethod['conditions'] is None or len(curMethod['conditions']) == 0:
                    statement['Resource'].append(curMethod['resourceArn'])
                else:
                    conditionalStatement = self._getEmptyStatement(effect)
                    conditionalStatement['Resource'].append(curMethod['resourceArn'])
                    conditionalStatement['Condition'] = curMethod['conditions']
                    statements.append(conditionalStatement)

            if statement['Resource']:
                statements.append(statement)

        return statements

    def allowAllMethods(self):
        '''Adds a '*' allow to the policy to authorize access to all methods of an API'''
        self._addMethod('Allow', HttpVerb.ALL, '*', [])

    def denyAllMethods(self):
        '''Adds a '*' allow to the policy to deny access to all methods of an API'''
        self._addMethod('Deny', HttpVerb.ALL, '*', [])

    def allowMethod(self, verb, resource):
        '''Adds an API Gateway method (Http verb + Resource path) to the list of allowed
        methods for the policy'''
        self._addMethod('Allow', verb, resource, [])

    def denyMethod(self, verb, resource):
        '''Adds an API Gateway method (Http verb + Resource path) to the list of denied
        methods for the policy'''
        self._addMethod('Deny', verb, resource, [])

    def allowMethodWithConditions(self, verb, resource, conditions):
        '''Adds an API Gateway method (Http verb + Resource path) to the list of allowed
        methods and includes a condition for the policy statement. More on AWS policy
        conditions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition'''
        self._addMethod('Allow', verb, resource, conditions)

    def denyMethodWithConditions(self, verb, resource, conditions):
        '''Adds an API Gateway method (Http verb + Resource path) to the list of denied
        methods and includes a condition for the policy statement. More on AWS policy
        conditions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition'''
        self._addMethod('Deny', verb, resource, conditions)

    def build(self):
        '''Generates the policy document based on the internal lists of allowed and denied
        conditions. This will generate a policy with two main statements for the effect:
        one statement for Allow and one statement for Deny.
        Methods that includes conditions will have their own statement in the policy.'''
        if ((self.allowMethods is None or len(self.allowMethods) == 0) and
                (self.denyMethods is None or len(self.denyMethods) == 0)):
            raise NameError('No statements defined for the policy')

        policy = {
            'principalId': self.principalId,
            'policyDocument': {
                'Version': self.version,
                'Statement': []
            }
        }

        policy['policyDocument']['Statement'].extend(self._getStatementForEffect('Allow', self.allowMethods))
        policy['policyDocument']['Statement'].extend(self._getStatementForEffect('Deny', self.denyMethods))

        return policy
```

Comment: Little note, I'm using Python 2.7 so my urllib is a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Following class verifies Cognito tokens. You are required to install [jose](https://pypi.org/project/python-jose/) and [pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/).

The implementation is derived from [this repo](https://github.com/MousaZeidBaker/auth), it contains more details, addiotional functionalitites, tests etc.

```
import json
import logging
import os
import time
import urllib.request
from typing import Dict, List

from jose import jwk, jwt
from jose.utils import base64url_decode
from pydantic import BaseModel


class JWK(BaseModel):
    """A JSON Web Key (JWK) model that represents a cryptographic key.

    The JWK specification:
    https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517
    """

    alg: str
    e: str
    kid: str
    kty: str
    n: str
    use: str


class CognitoAuthenticator:
    def __init__(self, pool_region: str, pool_id: str, client_id: str) -> None:
        self.pool_region = pool_region
        self.pool_id = pool_id
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.issuer = f"https://cognito-idp.{self.pool_region}.amazonaws.com/{self.pool_id}"
        self.jwks = self.__get_jwks()

    def __get_jwks(self) -> List[JWK]:
        """Returns a list of JSON Web Keys (JWKs) from the issuer. A JWK is a
        public key used to verify a JSON Web Token (JWT).

        Returns:
            List of keys
        Raises:
            Exception when JWKS endpoint does not contain any keys
        """

        file = urllib.request.urlopen(f"{self.issuer}/.well-known/jwks.json")
        res = json.loads(file.read().decode("utf-8"))
        if not res.get("keys"):
            raise Exception("The JWKS endpoint does not contain any keys")
        jwks = [JWK(**key) for key in res["keys"]]
        return jwks

    def verify_token(
        self,
        token: str,
    ) -> bool:
        """Verify a JSON Web Token (JWT).

        For more details refer to:
        https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

        Args:
            token: The token to verify
        Returns:
            True if valid, False otherwise
        """

        try:
            self._is_jwt(token)
            self._get_verified_header(token)
            self._get_verified_claims(token)
        except CognitoError:
            return False
        return True

    def _is_jwt(self, token: str) -> bool:
        """Validate a JSON Web Token (JWT).
        A JSON Web Token (JWT) includes three sections: Header, Payload and
        Signature. They are base64url encoded and are separated by dot (.)
        characters. If JWT token does not conform to this structure, it is
        considered invalid.

        Args:
            token: The token to validate
        Returns:
            True if valid
        Raises:
            CognitoError when invalid token
        """

        try:
            jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
            jwt.get_unverified_claims(token)
        except jwt.JWTError:
            logging.info("Invalid JWT")
            raise InvalidJWTError
        return True

    def _get_verified_header(self, token: str) -> Dict:
        """Verifies the signature of a a JSON Web Token (JWT) and returns its
        decoded header.

        Args:
            token: The token to decode header from
        Returns:
            A dict representation of the token header
        Raises:
            CognitoError when unable to verify signature
        """

        # extract key ID (kid) from token
        headers = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
        kid = headers["kid"]

        # find JSON Web Key (JWK) that matches kid from token
        key = None
        for k in self.jwks:
            if k.kid == kid:
                # construct a key object from found key data
                key = jwk.construct(k.dict())
                break
        if not key:
            logging.info(f"Unable to find a signing key that matches '{kid}'")
            raise InvalidKidError

        # get message and signature (base64 encoded)
        message, encoded_signature = str(token).rsplit(".", 1)
        signature = base64url_decode(encoded_signature.encode("utf-8"))

        if not key.verify(message.encode("utf8"), signature):
            logging.info("Signature verification failed")
            raise SignatureError

        # signature successfully verified
        return headers

    def _get_verified_claims(self, token: str) -> Dict:
        """Verifies the claims of a JSON Web Token (JWT) and returns its claims.

        Args:
            token: The token to decode claims from
        Returns:
            A dict representation of the token claims
        Raises:
            CognitoError when unable to verify claims
        """

        claims = jwt.get_unverified_claims(token)

        # verify expiration time
        if claims["exp"] < time.time():
            logging.info("Expired token")
            raise TokenExpiredError

        # verify issuer
        if claims["iss"] != self.issuer:
            logging.info("Invalid issuer claim")
            raise InvalidIssuerError

        # verify audience
        # note: claims["client_id"] for access token, claims["aud"] otherwise
        if claims["client_id"] != self.client_id:
            logging.info("Invalid audience claim")
            raise InvalidAudienceError

        # verify token use
        if claims["token_use"] != "access":
            logging.info("Invalid token use claim")
            raise InvalidTokenUseError

        # claims successfully verified
        return claims


class CognitoError(Exception):
    pass


class InvalidJWTError(CognitoError):
    pass


class InvalidKidError(CognitoError):
    pass


class SignatureError(CognitoError):
    pass


class TokenExpiredError(CognitoError):
    pass


class InvalidIssuerError(CognitoError):
    pass


class InvalidAudienceError(CognitoError):
    pass


class InvalidTokenUseError(CognitoError):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    auth = CognitoAuthenticator(
        pool_region=os.environ["AWS_COGNITO_REGION"],
        pool_id=os.environ["AWS_USER_POOL_ID"],
        client_id=os.environ["AWS_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"],
    )

    # note: if you are not using access token, see line 161
    access_token = "my_access_token"
    print(f"Token verified: {auth.verify_token(access_token)}")
```